# Where will be store removed files from PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I removed one of my files from a project in PhpStorm 3.0, but now i need it. 
Where will be store removed files from PhpStorm? ( on Linux )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/local-history.html) to restore your files.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly user files should be stored in `/home/[user]/PhpStorm`.

Application itself should be in `/opt/PhpStorm...`

Answer (score 0):

cntrl + shift + A  to find action after that search with => (local history) then select Show History